# How to find literal ? CRLF <anytext> in Notepad++ or Gawk

Tags: newline, notepad++, literals

I have a text file with a series of questions in it for an exam

The structure is

Question A?
potential answer 1
potential answer 2
potential answer 3
potential answer 4
potential answer 5

Question B?
potential answer 1
potential answer 2
potential answer 3
potential answer 4
potential answer 5

...

Question N?
potential answer 1
potential answer 2
potential answer 3
potential answer 4
potential answer 5

and I'm looking to change this example text:

```
Which of the following can you copy?
Indexes
Tables
Workspaces
Scripts
All the above
```

Into this text:

```
Which of the following can you copy?
{
Indexes
Tables
Workspaces
Scripts
All the above
}
```

In Notepad++ or Gawk

With one condition - If it already looks like the latter, leave it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done similar changes by concentrating on the blank line. I have added two blank lines at the top of the file and two more at the bottom of the file. Then run a find and replace. Search for `\r\n\r\n` and replace with `\r\n}\r\n\r\nWhich of the following can you copy?{\r\n` .

If the "*Which of the following can you copy?*" is just an example then the search string might be `\r\n\r\n(.*)\r\n` and the replacement `\r\n}\r\n\r\n\1{\r\n` .

Finally, delete the unwanted top and bottom of the file.

But - this does not check whether the file is already in the final format.